# Поменять сообщения пользователя

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
import config
import random

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.Token)

print("sdf")

@bot.message_handler(commands = ["start"])
def welcome(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Угадай число от 1 до 100")

    markup.add(item1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, выбери игру из списка ниже, возможны технические неполадки так как бот тестовый.",
        parse_mode = "html", reply_markup=markup)

rnum = random.randint(1, 100)
print("asd")
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ["text"])
def random_game(message):
        if message.chat.type == 'private':
            if message.text == "Угадай число от 1 до 100":
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я загадал число от 1 до 100, попробуй угадай!")
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, rnum)
                bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                print("sdf")
            while True: 
                if message.chat.type == "public":
                    pass
                    print("sasdasdasa")
                else:
                    guess = int(message.text)
                    if guess < rnum:
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "nope")
                        break
bot.polling(non_stop=1)
```

Короче, да, код ужасный потому что я только начинаю, дело в том что я хочу проверить текст пользователя и сравнить с загаданым числом, но текстом пользователя остается то что выводилось "Угадай число от 1 до 100", и я не знаю как сделать чтобы после этого пользователь вписал другое сообщение которое будет числом.

Comment: ну так если в коде написано "Угадай число от 1 до 100", то странно ожидать другой текст. Используй переменные и форматирование строк https://python-scripts.com/string-formatting